# Spring Data Elasticsearch external ES Server

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am using Spring Data ElasticSearch for my application, however Spring Data ElasticSearch embeds ES inside spring, is there anyway I can connect it to an external elasticsearch server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For connecting to node client (AKA embeded node)

```
  <elasticsearch:node-client id="client" local="true" cluster-name="testCluster" http-enabled="false"/>
```

To connect external server by specifying server nodes and cluster name , note that cluster-nodes argument can be multiple nodes comma separated

```
 <elasticsearch:transport-client id="client" cluster-name="elasticsearch" cluster-nodes="127.0.0.1:9300" />
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to an external cluster using transport client as in the following code.

```
<elasticsearch:transport-client id="elasticsearchClient" cluster-nodes="<ip>:<port>"/>
```

You can pass this to `elasticsearchtemplate` and use accordingly.